# Tailwind PrimeVue passthrough not working in Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, primevue

```
import path from 'path';

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  css: ['~/assets/css/main.css'],
  modules: ['nuxt-primevue', '@vueuse/nuxt'],
  primevue: {
      options: {
        unstyled: true
      },
      importPT: { from: '~/presets/lara' },
  },
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  },
})
```

I am not able to use passthrough in primevue components, components are working but, if i send passthrough as props for the component, the changes are not reflected.

But in my previous Vue project it was working fine, but not in nuxt

Tried adding important: true in tailwind config file